# A sebset of $\Bbb C^2$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $K\subset \Bbb R$ have Lebesgue measure $0$.
Then I think that the set
$$
\Omega:=\{(z, w)\in \Bbb C^2: |zw|\in K\}
$$
has $4$ dimensional measure $0$. 
If so, how to prove(or shortly explain) it?

Comment: Suppose $f\colon\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb R,(z,w)\mapsto\lvert zw\rvert$. Note that if $I$ is an interval such that $m(I)$ is small, then $f^{-1}(I)$ is measurable and $m(f^{-1}(I))$ is also small.

Comment: It seems not true that $m(f^{-1}(I)) is small.

Comment: Well, you can try $m(f^{-1}(I)\cap F)$ is small if $m(I)$ is small enough, for any compact set $F$, then $m(f^{-1}(K)\cap F)$ should be zero. I forgot to restrict the domain on a finite measure space.

Comment: I got it! It's perfect answer. Thank you so much.